# Calculate prefix product with std::exclusive_scan and execution policy std::execution::par

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, tbb

I'm calculating the [prefix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function) with [`std::exclusive_scan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/exclusive_scan)

```
#include <algorithm>/
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::exclusive_scan(std::begin(input), std::end(input),
                        std::begin(input),
                        1, std::multiplies<> {});

    std::cout << "exclusive_scan: "
    for (auto const product : input) {
        std::cout << product << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected `exclusive_scan: 1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320`.

Now I wanted to parallelize it with [`std::execution::par`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag) and changed the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::exclusive_scan(std::execution::par,
                        std::begin(input), std::end(input),
                        std::begin(input),
                        1, std::multiplies<> {});

    std::cout << "exclusive_scan: "
    for (auto const product : input) {
        std::cout << product << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

but now the output is `exclusive_scan: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

I'm using gcc 10.2.0 and linking against `-ltbb`.

Why can I not use `std::exclusive_scan` with `std::execution::par`?
Is something wrong how I implemented it?
What changes are necessary?

Comment: [Working version (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/Whqn9TY7M), the difference is that the output range is not the same as input one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `exclusive_scan` with default execution policy, as:

```
exclusive_scan(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), initial_value, operate)
```

what happens is:

```
initial_value_temp = operate(input[0], initial_value);
output[0] = initial_value;
initial_value = initial_value_temp

initial_value_temp = operate(input[1], initial_value);
output[1] = initial_value;
initial_value = initial_value_temp

     ⋮

initial_value_temp = operate(input[last], initial_value);
output[last] = initial_value;
initial_value = initial_value_temp
```

However when you are trying to apply `execution::par` on it, for some reason, probably for better parallelizations, it will work like:

```
output[0] = initial_value;
initial_value = operate(input[0], initial_value);

output[1] = initial_value;
initial_value = operate(input[1], initial_value);

     ⋮

output[last] = initial_value;
initial_value = operate(input[last], initial_value);
```

Both of them should work exactly the same, if `input` and `output` are different. However, the process breaks down when they are the same, which is what you were trying to do.

To fix it, the easiest way would be to create an output container:

```
std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

std::vector<int> output;
output.reserve(input.size());

std::exclusive_scan(std::execution::par, 
                    std::begin(input), 
                    std::end(input), 
                    std::back_inserter(output),
                    1, std::multiplies{});
```

---

- Note `execution::par` would actually try to distribute the entire task into different threads, then merge them later. There are many articles on how it should work. However, the main point here is you were trying to edit the input while producing outputs. And with only 9 numbers, it never created any parallel threads for me(creating one would probably be much slower).