# std::exclusive_scan with execution policy does not work in-place

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

cppreference says this for [std::exclusive_scan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/exclusive_scan):

> d_first   -   the beginning of the destination range; may be equal to first

So there should be no problem with using `std::exclusive_scan` in "in-place" mode overwriting the storage. However, with the libstdc++ implementation that comes with GCC 12.2.0, it does not work with the overloads that use an execution policy, even if it is `std::execution::seq`. Consider this example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    std::vector<int> vec(size);

    // without execution policy
    std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
    std::exclusive_scan(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), 0);
    assert(vec[0] == 0); // the first element should be 0
    assert(vec[size-1] == size-1); // the last element should be the sum

    // sequential execution policy
    std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
    std::exclusive_scan(std::execution::seq, vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), 0);
    assert(vec[0] == 0); // the first element should be 0
    assert(vec[size-1] == size-1); // the last element should be the sum

    // parallel execution policy
    std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
    std::exclusive_scan(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), 0);
    assert(vec[0] == 0); // the first element should be 0
    assert(vec[size-1] == size-1); // the last element should be the sum
}
```

See on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Yvax1dz7e

Is this a bug in the cppreference documentation or libstdc++ implementation? It actually *is possible* to implement a parallel in-place exclusive scan algorithm.

I know there is [Calculate prefix product with std::exclusive_scan and execution policy std::execution::par](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323455/calculate-prefix-product-with-stdexclusive-scan-and-execution-policy-stdexec) but it does not ask about a bug.

Comment: If this is a bug, then it is important to open an issue on the bug tracker of libstdc++ 1. so to check it is actually a bug and 2. so it can be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[exclusive.scan#8]](https://eel.is/c++draft/exclusive.scan#8) of the standard explicitly says:

> *Remarks*: `result` may be equal to `first`.

Also, latest MSVC, unlike GCC and Clang, accepts your code in C++17 mode: https://godbolt.org/z/78W9Wfbvh

So, this is a bug in libstdc++ implementation, while cppreference correctly represents standard's remark.

Comment: Thanks, I submitted a bug report with a link to the standard: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108236